# How to add a label to all words in a file?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, stanford-nlp, nltk-trainer

I have a file containing words, I want to read this file and add a label in front of all words. The label should be added on the right side of the words. eg. `book - "O"`, `Berlin - "O"`. How to do it in python? I have tried this code but not given my answer.

```
inp = open('Dari.pos', 'r')
out = open('DariNER.txt', 'w')

for line in iter(inp):
    word= line.__add__("O")
    out.write(word)
inp.close()
out.close()
```

Comment: First you read the text from the file, then add the label in front and finally save it. Can you show us what you have tried so far?

Comment: As @ViG said, show us what you have tried so far. Additionally, your question is highly vague! Can you please show as the inputs and what you expect as the outputs?

Comment: Actually, I can read a file but I dont know how to add a label in front of each word.

Comment: define label? hello -> labelhello? label, hello? label-hello? [(label, hello)]?

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("**why isn't this code working?**") must include 
the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code  necessary 
to reproduce it **in the question itself**. Questions without a **clear problem 
statement** are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and 
Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: I have a list of words, like books, shops .... Just I want to add in front of books a tab space then "O" in all words.

Comment: @TomDalton, the question is clear, and I have replied to other comments. Just add a label to each word in a file.but don't know how to do it

Comment: You have not provided any code, nor the specific problem you have with that code, nor the specific output you want. You are expecting us to donate our time to help you, it is in your interest to make it easy for us to help you. At the moment, it's unclear to me what you want or what you have tried, and so I can't help you.

Comment: @TomDalton I added the code, and it works now. Just let me know how to add it on the right side of the words with a tab space.

Comment: Thanks for editing the question to include your code. Can you now edit the question again to include examples of lines from the input file and how you want them to appear in the output file?

Comment: @quamrana, Thanks, I did, can you have a look on the code now.

Comment: @TomDalton, please have a look now.

Comment: @Tzomas, Can you have a look now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand the correct output format word-O, you can try something like this:

```
words = open('filename').read().split()
labeled_words = [word+"-O" for word in words]

# And now user your output format, each word a line, separate by tabs, whatever.
# For example new lines
with open('outputfile','w') as output:
    output.write("\n".join(labeled_words))
```

Comment: it's on the right side :S word + "-O"

Comment: that is left side from word that is the reference, just change word+"O" to "O"+word

Comment: I changed, but not work. In the input file on the left I have English Tag "NOUN" then Dari word "امریکا" and I want to add "O" beside "NOUN".

Answer (score 0):

In your updated question you show examples of words (I assume you mean lines) with some characters added to them:

```
eg. book - "O", Berlin - "O"
```

This modification to your code should produce that output:

```
for line in iter(inp):
    word = '{} - "O"'.format(line)
    out.write(word)
```

I ran a test with this code below:

```
inp = ['This is a book','I bought it in Berlin']

for line in iter(inp):
    word = '{} - "O"'.format(line)
    print(word)
```

Output:

```
This is a book - "O"
I bought it in Berlin - "O"
```